# Move excel worksheet in VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net

Moving excel workbook gives the following error "Invalid index"
oExcel the application.
Sheet1 and Sheet2 exist
Sheet2 has an index 2
Sheet1 has an index of 1

oExcel.Worksheets("Sheet1").Move.After = oExcel.WorkSheets("Sheet2")

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

`oExcel.Worksheets("Sheet1").Move( After := oExcel.WorkSheets("Sheet2") )`

Comment: Now I get  the error 'Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses'

Comment: Sorry, not a VB.NET user, but that error at least tells you exactly what needs to be changed.